# PHP-how does strtotime() work?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I'm working on an application which sends a request to a 3rd-party product licensing server, waits for a response, then sends a request to my server a few seconds later. Later, I compare the two records based on the date and time they were created. When I look at the times, they appear to be roughly 6 hours apart (presumably due to time zone differences). However, when I run each through PHP's strtotime() function, the results are only a few seconds apart. Here's an example:

```
echo strtotime("2013-04-29T14:55:47.707Z");
echo '<br>';
echo strtotime("2013-04-29 08:56:10");
```

displays as:

```
1367247347
1367247370
```

which is only a difference of 23 seconds, not 6 hours.

If I'm not providing any information about the time zone of each date string, how are they coming up so close together?

(Keep in mind that I'd love for these results to be correct; I'm just not sure how I'm getting them)

Comment: The numbers from `strtotime()` are [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The first time string is in the `UTC` timezone (denoted by the `Z` for "Zulu"). The second time string has no timezone specified so uses what is currently configured for your PHP, which has an offset of -6 hours from UTC.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that `.707Z` must be translating to some type of timezone information.

Comment: you default time zone is set to UTC so they are calculating within the same timezone. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) if you want different behavior

Answer (score 0):

You should really avoid using `strtotime` unless you absolutely have to. When you actually have the full date format, like you do, you should use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class built in to PHP.

This code should give you the correct UNIX timestamps. (You may not need to include the default timezone based on your server configuration. If you do, set it to your time zone.)

```
// You may be able to comment this out depending on your server configuration
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 

$dateone = new DateTime('2013-04-29T14:55:47.707Z');
$datetwo = new DateTime('2013-04-29 08:56:10');

echo $dateone->format('U');
echo "<br/>";
echo $datetwo->format('U');
```

Outputs:

```
1367247347
1367240170
```